# Redirect to index page reload after logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have done simple login authentication using angular js. , once you are logged in it will redirect to profile page after if i reload my profile page, again it will redirect to index page(login.html). i know this problem happens because of html5mode, so please try to give solution for this.

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <base href="/Angular-workouts/login/index.html" />
    <script src="../Angular-lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Angular-lib/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="../Bootstrap-lib/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
        font-family:Calibri;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <header>

  </header>
    <div class="container" ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

***login.html***

```
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4" ng-controller="loginController">
     <h2>Please Login</h2>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="username" placeholder="Enter Username" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter password" >
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="validate()">Login</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

***Javascript***

```
var mylogin = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
 mylogin.run(function ($browser) {
    $browser.baseHref = function () { return "/" };
  });
// configure our routes
mylogin.config(function ($routeProvider , $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the index page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/Angular-workouts/login/login.html'
        })

        // route for the profile page
        .when('/profile', {
            resolve: {

                "check": function ($location , $rootScope) {
                    if (!$rootScope.loggedIn) {
                        $location.path("/");
                    }


                }

            },
            templateUrl: '/Angular-workouts/login/profile.html'

        })

        // route for the error page
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: '/Angular-workouts/login/error.html'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});

mylogin.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {


});

mylogin.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {

    $scope.validate = function () {

        if ($scope.username == "admin" && $scope.password == "admin") {
            $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
            $location.path("/profile");

        }
        else {
            alert("invalid")
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: You need to preserve the user's log-in state using the browser's storage (either session or local). Currently, you are only storing it in-memory, which is wiped when you reload the page.